# System.UriFormatException : Invalid URI: Invalid port specified. in c#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

When I trying for unit testing,

I ended up error stating 'System.UriFormatException : Invalid URI: Invalid port specified.'
Code which showing error is ,

```
  public Dictionary<SensorMode, Uri> ImageSrc = new Dictionary<SensorMode, Uri>()
        {
            {SensorMode.f, new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/TS.png") },//towards to sensor image
            {SensorMode.b, new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/AS.png") },//away from the sensor image
            {SensorMode.c, new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/F.png") },//fast moving image
            {SensorMode.p, new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/S.png") },//slow moving image
            {SensorMode.x, new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/fail.png")}//fail image 
        };
```

Can anyone help me to solve this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because you're executing this code while the pack:// scheme is not yet registered. This scheme is registered when you create the Application object. You can add this code in the setup of your test fixture:

```
 [SetUp]
  public void OnTestInitialize()
  {
      UriParser.Register(new GenericUriParser(
      GenericUriParserOptions.GenericAuthority), "pack", -1);
  }
```